# How to parse data displayed in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, web-scraping, html5-canvas

I want to parse graph details displayed using HTML5 canvas element. When I inspect the element it looks just empty element. Is there any way to figure out content sources of canvas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Canvases are literally a canvas for graphics. Your best bet is to locate where the canvas is being rendered, then find where that data comes from.

Answer (score 1):

About your [last closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120262/how-to-click-on-html5-canvas-element-using-java-script)...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Graph reader
// @namespace   http://gm.wesley.eti.br
// @include     http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var tz = 60 * new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
(function recursive (x, l, f) {
    if (l.length) {
        if (x[l[0]]) {
            recursive(x[l.shift()], l, f);
        } else {
            setTimeout(recursive, 1000, x, l, f);
        }
    } else {
        f(x);
    }
}(unsafeWindow, ["qctg", "controller", "subset", "reach"], function (data) {
    // data is equals to unsafeWindow.qctg.controller.subset.reach

    var index = data.length - 1;
    alert([
        "DATE       " + new Date(1000 * (data[index].date + tz)),
        "PEOPLE     " + data[index].reach.PEOPLE.GLOBAL,
        "VISITS     " + data[index].reach.HOURLY_SESSIONS.GLOBAL,
        "PAGE VIEWS " + data[index].reach.ARRIVALS.GLOBAL,
    ].join("\n"));
}));
```

Comment: Thank for answer. I will re-open that question with the help of reputed users, then you can add this answer there. :-)